# How to open links from a mobile website using the respective native app

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, facebook

I am developing a mobile website. This is a normal HTML website (not a native app or PhoneGap or something of that sort, just a normal HTML website accessed through a URL on the browser).

The client wants to link to his respective Facebook / Pinterest / YouTube / Twitter / Google Plus profiles and pages, and if the user has the respective app installed on his smartphone, the app should open.

This seems to work for things like YouTube and Google Plus, but Facebook doesn't open the app but it just opens in the browser. I am testing using Chrome on a Nexus 5 (Android 4.4.2), and most probably I will have a different effect on iOS when I test it with an iPhone.

From the research I have done so far there also seems to be a different URL scheme for iPhone apps, such as `fb://` for Facebook. Does this mean I have to detect the user agent and if it's an iOS device use this, while if it's an Android use the other?

When I looked around for a standard way or some JavaScript routine to do this most information that comes up is relevant to developing native apps rather than mobile HTML web sites. Is there a straightforward way to achieve this (in HTML and JavaScript), that caters at least for the popular smart phone platforms (Android and iOS primarily, and Windows Phone 8 ideally too)?

Answer (score 0):

you must check the user agent (android/ios) and generate links accordingly.
For example on Android an app may register itself to handle kind of http link (ie http://facebook.com/...) and on ios it can't be made (except some special cases).
so you have to generate approporiate links according to the user agent.

regarding a js performing this - I don't know one around but go ahead and do it yourself - it's very simple :)

Good luck

Comment: You haven't told me anything I didn't know yet. What I am looking for is how best to do this.